# error at line 6 ora-00933 sql command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

Tables:

```
Patient (PatientID, FamilyName, GivenName, Address, Suburb, State, PostCode) 
Doctor (ProviderNo, Name)
Item (ItemNo, Description, Fee)
Account (AccountNo, ProviderNo, PatientID, Date)
AccountLine (AccountNo, ItemNo)
```

Qns:Name of patients who have been treated by Dr Brian or who have had an Extended Consultation

My Ans:

```
select p.GivenName ||''|| p.FamilyName as Name
   FROM DTOOHEY.Account A, DTOOHEY.Patient P, Dtoohey.Doctor D, Dtoohey.Item I, Dtoohey.AccountLine AL
WHERE P.PATIENTID = A.PATIENTID
AND A.PROVIDERNO = D.PROVIDERNO
AND I.ITEMNO = AL.ITEMNO
WHERE D.NAME = 'Dr Brian' or I.Description = 'Extended Consultation';
```

> ```
> MyError: WHERE D.NAME = 'Dr Brian' or I.Description = 'Extended Consultation'
> * ERROR at line 6: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> ```

Where did I go wrong???

Answer (score 1):

You already have a `WHERE` clause so the duplicate one is causing the error. If you want to add conditions, use boolean operators

```
AND (D.NAME = 'Dr Brian' OR I.Description = 'Extended Consultation')
```